# Firebase storage and authentication work, but realtime database doesn't

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In the project I am doing, the user's input(uid, email, username, image url) should go to the Realtime database but it does not update. Authentication and storage do, they are working without problem,the user is authetnticated and the posted image goes to storage. The rules of the database are set to "true". It is weird because my app has the functionality to edit your user information and display it on profile, and that works,the edited input shows on the app, but the data is nowhere to be found in Firebase. I don't know where the problem could be. Here is the code for user's to upload their information:

```
 private fun saveUserInfo(fullName: String, userName: String, email: String,progressDialog:ProgressDialog) {
    val currentUserId=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val userRef : DatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

    val userMap=HashMap<String,Any>()
    userMap["uid"]=currentUserId
    userMap["username"]=userName.toLowerCase()
    userMap["email"]=email
    userMap["image"]="imageurl"

    userRef.child(currentUserId).setValue(userMap)
        .addOnCompleteListener {task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Account has been created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                    .child("Follow").child(currentUserId)
                    .child("Following").child(currentUserId)
                    .setValue(true)


                val intent=Intent(this@SignUpActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
            }
            else
            {
                val message=task.exception!!.toString()
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error : $message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                progressDialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: My first hunch is that it's a security rules issue. Can you add a completion listener to detect that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback?

Comment: You should always write code to check for errors when working with Firebase.  `setValue` can result in an error, but you're not checking that at all here, which means you'll never know if something goes wrong.

Comment: If you log the error, are you getting something printed out in the logcat? And since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).